# R bslib theme some variables are not accepted

Tags: r, shiny, bootstrap-5, bslib

I have a `bslib` app where I want to customize the navbar, brand, and some other elements.
Specifically, I want to customize the `navbar-brand-color`, `navbar-brand-hover-color`, and `navbar-active-color` colors.

Based on my understanding of bslib, this should do the job, but some values are not taken and the default values used.
When I manually override the CSS values, it works but that defeats the purpose of `bs_theme`.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

theme <- bs_theme(
  version = 5,
  "navbar-bg" = "green",                    # works
  "navbar-brand-color" = "red !important",  # does not work!!!
  "navbar-brand-hover-color" = "salmon !important", # does not work!!!
  "navbar-active-color" = "gray !important", # does not work!!!
  "nav-link-color" = "yellow !important",   # works
  "nav-link-hover-color" = "orange !important", # works
)

ui <- page(
  theme = theme,
  # # manually overriding the CSS values works, but defeats the purpose of theme
  # tags$head(tags$style("
  #    .navbar-brand {color: red;}
  #    .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-brand:focus {color: salmon !important;}
  #    a.nav-link.active {color: gray !important;}
  #   ")),
  navset_bar(
    title = "Brand Name",
    nav_panel("Active Tab", h2("Active")),
    nav_panel("Inctive Tab", h2("Inactive"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look [here](https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/bs5-variables/index.html), you will notice that you need to use `"navbar-light-brand-color" = "red !important",` .  You were missing "light" in your variable.

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

theme <- bs_theme(
  version = 5,
  "navbar-bg" = "green",                    # works
  "navbar-light-active-color" = "gray !important", # does work!!!
  "navbar-light-brand-color" = "red !important",  # does work!!!
  "navbar-light-brand-hover-color" = "salmon !important", # does work!!!
  "nav-link-color" = "yellow !important",   # works
  "nav-link-hover-color" = "orange !important", # works
)

ui <- page(
  theme = theme,
  # # manually overriding the CSS values works, but defeats the purpose of theme
  # tags$head(tags$style("
  #    .navbar-brand {color: red;}
  #    .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-brand:focus {color: salmon !important;}
  #    a.nav-link.active {color: gray !important;}
  #   ")),
  navset_bar(
    title = "Brand Name",
    nav_panel("Active Tab", h2("Active")),
    nav_panel("Inactive Tab", h2("Inactive"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I get it from the [docs](https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/bs5-variables/index.html#nav-link-padding-y) there are no bootstrap 5 Sass variables for the non-working cases. But of course could you add your own using `bs_add_variables()`. These variables can then be applied via and used in `bs_add_rules`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'bslib'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     page

theme <- bs_theme(
  version = 5,
  "navbar-bg" = "green", # works
  "nav-link-color" = "yellow !important", # works
  "nav-link-hover-color" = "orange !important" # works
) |> 
  bs_add_variables(
    "navbar-brand-color" = "red !important",
    "navbar-active-color" = "gray !important",
    "navbar-brand-hover-color" = "salmon !important"
  ) |> 
  bs_add_rules(
    list(
      ".navbar-brand { color: $navbar-brand-color}",
      ".navbar-brand:hover { color: $navbar-brand-hover-color}",
      ".navbar .active { color: $navbar-active-color}"  
    )
  )

ui <- page(
  theme = theme,
  navset_bar(
    title = "Brand Name",
    nav_panel("Active Tab", h2("Active")),
    nav_panel("Inctive Tab", h2("Inactive"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5661
```

[image]

[image]